# Cannot answer question because reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Sorry for the trouble, but I am trying to answer a question again, and I can't because not enough rep.

I actually have enough, but because of bounties, it put me below the required amount. This is the one I want to answer:

[Force links to open in the app, not the default browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37549/force-links-to-open-in-the-app-not-the-default-browser)

Comment: Hello Zombo. I have unprotected the question. You can ping us in [chat] if you find a post you can answer but cannot do so because of its protection flag.